# Cron is not running at specified time in moodle?

Tags: php, cron, moodle

Cron is not running at specified time in moodle?

1.I just created an cron job like a 
`function cron(){}` in **block_plugin** and i written an code to insert records in db and i set time `$plugin->cron= 1*60;` in **version.php**. its inserting data into db when i am running `mysite.com/admin/cron.php`.

2.Its not working for every specific time(automatically for every 1 min).I checked db after 1min without running yoursite.com/admin/cron.php file its ideal. please help in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not manually running admin/cron.php, then have you set up something to automatically call this on a schedule? (Or admin/cli/cron.php)?

If you have not set up an automatic process to run the Moodle cron and have not called it manually, then none of the cron processes will happen.

Note that specifying 60 seconds is the *minimum* time between your code running - it will depend on how long the other cron processes take (I've seen large sites where cron can take 30-40 min to run at times) and how often the automated process calls it (could be every 1 min, but many sites set it to every 5-10min, or longer, to reduce server load).